# Splitting scanf input into arrays until EOF

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, eof

Looking to read in using scanf but I want to stop reading if I encounter a ',' '\0' (newline) or EOF

I'm not really sure how to stop achieve this.

I was using

```
 char * aBuff;
 char * bBuff;
 char * cBuff;

 //read in the first three lines and put them into char arrays
 //while (scan() != (',' || '\0' || EOF))  //was trying to put it into a while loop, wasn't sure
 scanf("%s", aBuff);
 scanf("%s", bBuff);
 scanf(%s, cBUff);
```

I plan on taking the input and putting them into separate arrays.  Basically take input until a , or new line and place that data into an array and continue this process until the end of file.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf()` is not a practical method to read until encountering `','`, `'\0'`,  or `EOF`.  Use `fgetc()`.

The biggest problem is specifying `'\0'` in the format of `scanf()`.  Example: with format `"%[^,\0]"`, `scanf()` only reads `"%[^,"` as it stops at the embedded `'\0'`.  So with an invalid format specifier --> undefined behavior.

```
size_t ReadX(char *dest, size_t size) {
  size_t len = 0;
  if (size) {
    while (--size > 0) {
      int ch = fgetc(stdin);
      if (ch == 0 || ch == ',' || ch == EOF) break;  // maybe add \n too.
      *dest[len++] = ch;
    }
    *dest[len] = '\0';
  }
  return len;  // or maybe return the stopping ch
}
```

---

`scanf()` could be use if code used the ponderous:

```
scanf("%[\1\2\3...all_char_codes_min_char_to_max_char_except_,_and\0]%*c", &s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [scansets](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scansets-in-c/)

scanf() should stop on EOF, but you'd want to maybe do something like this:

```
scanf("%[^,\0]", &s);
```

Comment: `scanf()` will only see the format up to the `'\0'`.  `"%[^,\0]"` will appear as `"%[^,"`.